# JavaFx HtmlEditor demo freeze on Windows 10 / Jdk 8u65

Tags: windows, javafx, freeze, html-editor

I'm testing JavaFx and I tried a simple HtmlEditor demo. Everything seems ok, the editors appears, I can type text, but if I click on a pull down menu (ex. to change the font size) the application freeze, I get a black rectangle where the menu is suppose to appear.

I'm on Windows 10 64Bits, JDK 8u65, with IntelliJ

- I Tested on another windows computer, with a fresh Java install same
  problem
- I tested creating a Java application, and a JavaFx    application
  same problem
- I Tested on a mac (recent, bought 2 months    ago), the demo works
  perfectly

Here is the example code I found on the web :

```
package Test;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.web.HTMLEditor;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
stage.setTitle("HTMLEditor Sample");
stage.setWidth(400);
stage.setHeight(300);
final HTMLEditor htmlEditor = new HTMLEditor();
htmlEditor.setPrefHeight(245);
Scene scene = new Scene(htmlEditor);
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
launch(args);
}
}
```

Comment: The HTMLEditor should function the same regardless of what OS it is running on.  Given your app works on OS X but not Windows 10, that would be a bug, which should be filed at: http://bugreport.java.com

Comment: It's done, I've filled a bug report at the given URL

Comment: I tested with the latest JDK 8u66 and now it works fine on Windows 10.